# How to use a template of a template of 2 classes which one is hereditary of the other class

Tags: c++, class, templates

How can you use a template of a template? Following problem is given:

You have two classes (just a simple overview to show my point) :

```
class one
{
private:
   int data;
public:
   one();
   int getData();
   void setData(int s);
}

class two: public one
{
private:
   one * current;
public:
   two();
   one * function1();
   one * function2(one * s);
   void add(int d);
   void add(int d, one * s);
}
```

now I would do Template1 (of class one) this way:

```
template <class T>
class one
{
private:
   T data;
public:
   one();
   T getData();
   void setData(T s);
}
```

In one function of class two I have to create a object of class one. Now I'm not sure how to create template of class two. My idea was:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class two: public one
{
private:
   T2 current;
public:
   two();
   T2 function1();
   T2 function2(T2);
   void add(T1 d);
   void add(T1 d, T2 s);
}
```

But then If I have to create for example in function1() an object of class one I have to create it like:

```
one<int> s = new one;
```

My Problem is I will not use a static type so I would try this:

```
one<T1> s = new one;
```

Hope you  can give me a correct form of the use of templates in my classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `two` only needs a single template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class two: public one<T>
{
private:
   one<T>* current;
public:
   two();
   one<T>* function1();
   one<T>* function2(one<T>*);
   void add(T d);
   void add(T d, one<T>* s);
};
```

live example: https://ideone.com/nrTK6C

Comment: Can I create then in function2 in this way: one<T> * s = new one<T>? Or is it not possible?

Comment: @missjohanna, yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Well the correct syntax would just involve using `one<T>`:

```
template <class T>
class two: public one<T>
{
private:
   one<T>* current;
public:
   two();
   one<T>* function1();
   one<T>* function2(one<T>*);
   void add(T d);
   void add(T d, one<T>* s);
}
```

It seems a little odd to both derive from a class and hold a pointer to the an object of the same class, but I'll assume you have a reasonable use-case.

Comment: In my case I have to use the second class to control the first class. Its going to be a ringlist and my Prof told me to do it this way. First class have a data segment and 2 pointer (element before and element after). Second class should also an element but with some control options like current element, headelement and tailelement. If you have an other solution please tell me. I want to learn!

Comment: That doesn't seem unreasonable, but I would probably have the controlling class as a separate class which just stores a pointer to the head and defines all the necessary operations.

Comment: Yeah I was going to do this aswell but he wanted to have the first element with creating the list by itself. Maybe its also due to not use an extern class and stay "privat".

Answer (score 0):

That operation is not possible.

Firstly, your class `two` must specify `one`'s template parameters when deriving from it.

Secondly, you cannot use inheritance to dodge the fact that C++ is a statically typed language. You *must* know all the types of the type that you are using. If `one` is a template, you *must* specify the template parameter for it to be a complete type that you can actually use. You cannot simply wish the parameter away.

You have only two choices. Specify a subset of `one`'s interface that does not depend on the parameter, have `one` inherit from that, and then use that. Alternatively, you could simply pass in the appropriate parameter to the user of `one`.

Comment: I think by "I will not use a static type" OP just means that it'll be a template parameter rather than something they explicitly specify, as opposed to what "static type" actually means.

Comment: Yeah exactly what TartanLlama said. I meant to use a type of my own definition. Sorry If I said it in a false way.